# "ER_UNKNOWN_TABLE: Unknown table 'products' in field list"

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

I'm using mysql and typeorm with nodejs. When I try to update a product, it throws this error. Any ideas of how to solve it?

Ps: The error happens only while I try to update. I can create products normally.

I tryed to use the createQueryBuilder, it throws the same error.

The entity:

```
@Entity('products')
class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;
  @Column('varchar')
  name: string;
  @Column('enum')
  genre: Genre;
  @Column('varchar')
  color: string;
  @Column('enum')
  size: Size;
  @Column('enum')
  status: Status;
  @Column('datetime')
  created_at: Date;
  @Column('varchar')
  obs?: string;
  @Column('float')
  sale_value: number;
  @Column('float')
  purchase_value: number;
  @Column('enum')
  purchase_type: Purchase_type;
  @Column('varchar')
  brand: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.products, { eager: true })
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Provider, provider => provider.products, { eager: true })
  provider: Provider;

  @ManyToOne(() => Category, category => category.products, { eager: true })
  category: Category;

  @ManyToOne(() => Mold, (mold: Mold) => mold.products, { eager: true })
  mold: Mold;

  @ManyToMany(() => Register, registers => registers.products)
  registers: Register[];
}
export default Product;
```

The update:

```
await productRepository.update(id, {
        name: product.name,
        genre: product.genre,
        color: product.color,
        size: product.size,
        status: product.status,
        obs: product.obs,
        sale_value: product.sale_value,
        purchase_value: product.purchase_value,
        purchase_type: product.purchase_type,
        brand: product.brand,
        category: categoryObject,
        mold: moldObject,
        provider: providerObject,
        user: userObject,
      });
```

The table:
[image]

Comment: Is the name of this table `products` or `product` ? (I do see `name: product.name,` without 's')

Comment: I used the map function, so "products" is the name of an array, and "product" is each data. The table's name is products.